# how to query connected graph using neo4jclient like Master detail SQL in EF

Tags: neo4jclient

I am new to the Neo4jClient as well as Neo4J so was not sure how to query for the data and get a master detail like data in the neo4j. Let me explain this with an example:

lets suppose I have a graph as below:

```
root -[:DEFINES] -> Shipment 1 
                -[:HAS_CONSIGNMENT]->Consignment 1
                            -[:HAS_ITEM]->Load Item 11
                            -[:HAS_ITEM]->Load Item 12
                            -[:HAS_CONSIGNEE]->Consignee 1
                -[:HAS_CONSIGNMENT]->Consignment 2
                            -[:HAS_ITEM]->Load Item 21
                            -[:HAS_ITEM]->Load Item 22
                            -[:HAS_CONSIGNEE]->Consignee 2
```

now suppose I want to get all the graph t o populate my Domain Model like below

```
public class Shipment
{
    public List<Consignment> Consignments {get; set;}
}

 public class Consignment
 {
     public List<LoadItem> LoadItems {get; set;}
     public Consignee ShippedTo {get; set;}
 }

 public class LoadItem
 {
 }
```

i know that I can probably build a Cypher query like below 
How to retrieve connected graph using neo4jclient

```
query = client.Cypher.Start(new { root = client.RootNode }).
            Match("root-[:DEFINES]->load-[:HAS_CONSIGNMENT]->consignments -[:HAS_ITEM]->loadItem").Match("consignments-[:HAS_CONSIGNEE]->consignee").
            Where((Load load) => load.Id == myId).
            Return(
            (load,consignments, loaditems)=>
            new {
                loadInfo = load.As<Node<Load>>(),
                consignments = consignments.CollectAs<Consignment>(),
                loadItems = loaditems.CollectAs<LoadItem>()
            });
```

but I am not sure how this can be converted to represent the second level of list that gives me that Consignment 2 has Load Item 21 & 22 where as Consignment 1 has Item 11 & 12.

can some one please help me understand how this works as I primarily have been working in the EF and the graph query is really new to me.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, this is the way I've got this working (I'm pretty sure Tatham will come along with a better answer - so hold out for a bit)

```
public static ICollection<Shipment> Get()
{
    var query = GraphClient.Cypher
        .Start(new {root = GraphClient.RootNode})
        .Match(
            string.Format("root-[:{0}]->shipment-[:{1}]-consignments-[:{2}]->loadItem", Defines.TypeKey, HasConsignment.TypeKey, HasItem.TypeKey),
            string.Format("consignments-[:{0}]->consignee", HasConsignee.TypeKey)
        )
        .Return((shipment, consignments, loadItem, consignee) =>
        new
        {
            Shipment = shipment.As<Node<Shipment>>(),
            Consignment = consignments.As<Consignment>(),
            LoadItem = loadItem.CollectAs<LoadItem>(),
            Consignee = consignee.As<Consignee>(),
        });

    var results = query.Results.ToList();
    var output = new List<Node<Shipment>>();

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        var shipmentOut = output.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Reference == result.Shipment.Reference);
        if (shipmentOut == null)
        {
            shipmentOut = result.Shipment;
            shipmentOut.Data.Consignments = new List<Consignment>();
            output.Add(shipmentOut);
        }

        result.Consignment.LoadItems = new List<LoadItem>();
        result.Consignment.LoadItems.AddRange(result.LoadItem.Select(l => l.Data));
        shipmentOut.Data.Consignments.Add(result.Consignment);
    }

    return output.Select(s => s.Data).ToList();
}
```

This will get you all the Shipments and Consignments etc.
*However* I note you do: `.Where((Load load) => load.Id == myId)` which implies you know the shipment id.

As a consequence, we can simplify the code a little bit - as we don't need to use 'root', and we can pass in the Shipment ID.

```
public static Shipment Get2(NodeReference<Shipment> shipmentNodeReference)
{
    var query = GraphClient.Cypher
        .Start(new {shipment = shipmentNodeReference})
        .Match(
            string.Format("shipment-[:{0}]-consignments-[:{1}]->loadItem", HasConsignment.TypeKey, HasItem.TypeKey), 
            string.Format("consignments-[:{0}]->consignee", HasConsignee.TypeKey)
        )
        .Return((shipment, consignments, loadItem, consignee) =>
        new {
            Shipment = shipment.As<Node<Shipment>>(),
            Consignment = consignments.As<Consignment>(),
            LoadItem = loadItem.CollectAs<LoadItem>(),
            Consignee = consignee.As<Consignee>(),
        });

    var results = query.Results.ToList();

    //Assuming there is only one Shipment returned for a given ID, we can just take the first Shipment.
    Shipment shipmentOut = results.First().Shipment.Data;
    shipmentOut.Consignments = new List<Consignment>();
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        result.Consignment.ShippedTo = result.Consignee;
        result.Consignment.LoadItems = new List<LoadItem>();
        result.Consignment.LoadItems.AddRange(result.LoadItem.Select(l => l.Data));
        shipmentOut.Consignments.Add(result.Consignment);
    }

    return shipmentOut;
}
```

For your info, the DataElements I was using were:

```
public class Shipment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Consignment> Consignments { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return Id; }
}

public class Consignment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<LoadItem> LoadItems { get; set; }
    public Consignee ShippedTo { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return Id; }
}

public class Consignee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return Name; }
}

public class LoadItem
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return Item; }
}
```

With relationships all defined like:

```
public class HasConsignment : Relationship, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<Shipment>, IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<Consignment>
{
    public const string TypeKey = "HAS_CONSIGNMENT";

    public HasConsignment() : base(-1) {}
    public HasConsignment(NodeReference targetNode): base(targetNode) {}
    public HasConsignment(NodeReference targetNode, object data) : base(targetNode, data) {}

    public override string RelationshipTypeKey { get { return TypeKey; } }
}
```

(with obvious changes where needed)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply, I really appreciate it. 
I think I am getting a hold of this now, what I was missing here was the proper Return in my query. I  was also collecting the consignments along with LoadItems as a result the the foreach loop below was giving me wrong data. So I think the key here is to get this projection defined properly so that the "results" can be looped in the way we want.